# Creating a fixed layout on bottom of the toolbar with shadow

Tags: android, android-layout

What I want to do is specify in the image below:

[image: Telegram]

My question is how to creating this layout with shadow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a layout like this

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
    <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/info_message_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:visibility="visible">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/home.info_message_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/message_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



And set the visibility to VISIBLE when your want to show it
```

Answer (score 0):

create drawable inside xml file my_shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape 
            android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        <padding android:bottom="2dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape 
            android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Add background of ur layout

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_shadow"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
```